# Retrieve name of RabbitMQ Queue where message was consumed from

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Using a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` that is attached to multiple queues and configured with a `ChannelAwareMessageListener`. Is it possible to determine which queue a message has been consumed from? In particular if the message was routed to the queue from an Exchange.

It looks that if a message is sent directly to a queue that the `MessageProperties#getReceivedRoutingKey` will contain the queue name but if the message is routed to a queue via an Exchange then this information contains the routing key that was used.

I'm looking for a mechanism that would allow this information to be extracted correctly regardless of how the message was delivered to the queue. Or a mechanism to enrich the information with a header containing this information on the RabbitMQ side.

Comment: When messages are sent directly to a queue, they are actually sent to a direct exchange. This direct exchange interprets the routing key as the queue name to which it must forward the message. That's why the routing key is identical to the queue name in that case.

Comment: Messages don't contain any information, where they are routed to (and I think that's reasonable). In this scenario, I think the consumer is the one in charge to know from which queue it received a message. Can you add more information on your scenario, e.g. why you need to know the queue name? Maybe another messaging pattern will fit better.

Comment: Messages do actually contain the received exchange (or it can be determines by the Spring AMQP implementation not sure which) so there is some routing information. I'm just looking to get the same information about which queue it might have come from. I have a consumer attached to multiple queues and I can't determine from which queue a message comes from. I could attach my consumers to just a single queue and then I could determine the queue. Is seems that each connection to a queue is given a consumer_tag and with this it should be possible to determine the queue but it isn't exposed.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to add the queue name to slf4j MDC context.

The only solution I have found is to subclass `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and set a ThreadLocal variable for the queue name or in my case the MDC context (which is basically threadlocals).

Because `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` still doesn't know exactly which queue (you can bind multiple queues to a container) you will have to allow only single queue per container which in my opinion is what you should do regardless.

In my companies own code base we have a magical `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` that does the creation of custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` based on routing annotations (think spring mvc `@RequestMapping` for amqp). If there is interest perhaps we can expedite opensourcing it.

Comment: That's pretty much what we have ended up doing as well.